An application of Hadamard's three-line theorem
Let $S$ an open sector between two rays from the origin, angle of the sector being $\frac{\pi}{\beta}$. The function $f$ is continuous on the closure of $S$ and holomorphic on $S$. If $|f(z)| \leq 1$ for $z \in \partial S$ and $|f(z)| \leq Ce^{|z|^\alpha}$ for $z \in  S$, where $C>0$ and $0<\alpha<\beta$ constants, then $|f(z)| \leq 1$ for $z \in S$.
My attempt was similar to the proof of the Hadamard's three circle theorem, I defined a function $g(z)=f(e^{-iz})$, hoping to translate the angle restriction to the real part restriction, but I can't see how I can bound the function.

don't you need a condition on $\alpha$ wr $\beta$? (eg if $\beta=1$ and the sector is the upper half plane, $f(z)=\sin z$ satisfies the required conditions with $\alpha=1$ but is not bounded in the sector)

@Conrad you're right, I edited the question now

I guess we assume $\beta >  1/2$(though the statement is true for $\beta \le 1/2$ in the sense that a function of order strictly less than $1/2$ cannot be bounded on a half line) and then the easiest way to do it is to rotate the sector so the negative half line is not in it, use the principal logarithm to define $g(w)=f(w^{1/\beta})$ so the sector becomes a half plane, rotate again to get $h$ and the right half plane and consider $H_{\epsilon}(z)=h(z)\exp(-\epsilon z^{\gamma})$ for some fixed $\alpha/\beta< \gamma<1$. show $H_{\epsilon}$ is bounded by maximum modulus and let $\epsilon \to 0$

@Conrad Thanks a lot!

happy to be of help
